# Metric analogues of bounded variation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

A function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is said to be of *bounded variation* if
$$ \sup_I \sum_{i=1}^n |f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})| \le V $$
for some finite $V>0$, where the supremum is over all finite partitions
$I=(a=x_0<x_1<\ldots<x_n=b)$ of $[a,b]$. I am looking for metric-space analogues of this notion.

One natural idea is to consider a function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$, where $(X,d)$ is a bounded metric space. We can define $f$ to be of bounded variation if
$$ \sup_{\mathcal{P}} \sum_{A\in\mathcal{P}} (\sup_A f-\inf_A f) \le V,$$
where $\mathcal{P}$ is the collection of all finite partitions of $X$. Has this notion been studied somewhere?

EDIT: Following @August Cleaner's comment: of course something is missing from the above: the metric! I should have defined it as something like
$$ \sup_{\epsilon>0}\sup_{\mathcal{P}_\epsilon} \sum_{A\in\mathcal{P}_\epsilon} (\sup_A f-\inf_A f) \le V,$$
where $\mathcal{P}_\epsilon$ is a finite partition where each block has diameter at most $\epsilon$. That at least agrees with the standard definition on $[a,b]$, I think.

EDIT II: Following Martin Hairer's example, here's a third attempt. For $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in X$, we can define the Voronoi partition induced by this finite set: every $x\in X$ is associated with the closest $x_i$. [There's the issue of how to break ties, but we're going to consider *all* such partitions and hence all possible tie-breaking schemes.] Let $\mathcal{P}_n$ be the collection of all Voronoi partitions induced by $n$ points, and say that
$f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ has bounded variation if
$$ \sup_{n>0}\sup_{\mathcal{P}_n} \sum_{A\in\mathcal{P}_n} (\sup_A f-\inf_A f) \le V.$$
Any comments on this definition?

Comment: I turn your attention to the fact that the suggested notion is quite different from the classical, e.g. the function $y=x$ on $[0,1]$ has infinite variation. Also this notion does not depend on the metric.

Comment: You're of course right, @AugustCleaner! I tried to fix this in the edited version.

Comment: Blocks in a partition don't need to be connected. In particular, one can easily have a partition of $[0,1]$ into $1/\epsilon^2$ blocks of diameter $\epsilon$, so the identity map still has infinite variation with the new definition. There is a notion of BV for functions of several real variables (see Wikipedia), but I am not sure that it generalises well. One naive generalisation would be to ask that $f\circ g$ is BV, uniformly over all $g \colon \mathbb{R} \to X$ having Lipschitz constant $1$.

Comment: Thank you for that example, @MartinHairer. Rather than risk further embarrassment with additional edits, let me try to continue in the comments. Suppose I define $\mathcal{P}_n$ to be the Voronoi partition induced by some $n$ points, and define the variation to be the supremum over all $\mathcal{P}_n$. Does this still admit pathological examples?

Comment: There is some notion of BV functions for metric measure spaces, which seems more natural when looking at the definition for BV in several real variables. Google gives a bunch of results, two of which are http://cvgmt.sns.it/paper/2738/ and http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021782403000369

Comment: For your EDIT II: let your metric space be $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and let $f(x,y) = x$. Let $n > 1$. Take $(x_i,y_i) = (0, i / (n-1))$ for $i < n$. Then for the $\mathcal{P}_n$ adapted to $\{(x_i,y_i)\}_{i = 0, \ldots, n-1}$ you have that $$ \sum_{A\in \mathcal{P}_n} (\sup_A f - \inf_A f) = n $$ So after taking the sup in $n$ you get that this function has infinite total variation by your definition.

Comment: On a related note, have you already considered the following: http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/ASNSP/ASNSP_1990_4_17_3/ASNSP_1990_4_17_3_439_0/ASNSP_1990_4_17_3_439_0.pdf

Comment: Very nice example, @WillieWong, and thanks Suvrit for the link. I was also pointed to http://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.6897v1.pdf . So I guess it's time to quite amateur conjecturing and start reading...

Comment: JFYI: the paper on arXiv you linked to in your last comment, in spite of the title, actually considers metric _measure_ spaces, and not just metric spaces.

Comment: Maybe a better way to go about it is to recall that $f\in BV$ if and only if (the distribution) $f'$ is a measure, and then generalize this condition.

Comment: @WillieWong One last attempt before giving this a rest. What if we consider an $\epsilon$-net (i.e., minimal cover/maximal packing), and then take $\mathcal{P}_n$ to be the Voronoi regions induced by the net points?

Comment: The scaling is still not right in two dimensions. Again let $f(x,y) = x$ on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. The lattice of multiples of $1/k$ forms more-or-less a $1/k$-net. For each of the squares you have $\sup f - \inf f = 1/k$. And you have a total of $k^2$ squares. Take $k\to \infty$ you still get blow-up. The $\sup f - \inf f$ definition captures what I feel more like a 1 dimension effect. Summing over a 2-dimensional (or higher) grid will always lead to blow-up.

Comment: Thanks again. I guess there's a reason why the Hardy-Krause extension to higher dimensions is so complicated.